# PHP Get the data from database follow the ID

Tags: php, database

I cannot find out what is the problems. My McReport.php will display all the data that i  key in before from database. I only want to display the data in McReport.php that use the Id from makemc.php. Please help me find out the way to solve the problem. Thank you.

```
//makemc.php database
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){
$AddMCQ = "INSERT INTO tblmc(Id,Name,FromDate,ToDate,Reason) VALUES('".$_POST['txtNo']."','".strtoupper($_POST['txtName'])."','".$_POST['txtFrom']."','".$_POST['txtTo']."','".strtoupper($_POST['txtReason'])."')";
$AddMCResult = mysql_query($AddMCQ,$link);

if($AddMCResult)
{
  echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
  echo "alert('Record Added.');\n";
  echo "window.location='McReport.php'";
  echo "</script>";
}

//McReport.php
<?php 
include("database.php"); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblmc") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "<p align='center'><b>Dr. Ting EE Medical Clinic</b></p>";
echo "<p align='center'><font size='2'>MEDICAL CERTIFICATE</font></p>"; 

while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{
$old_from_date = $row['FromDate'];
$old_from_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_from_date);
$new_from_date = date('d/m/Y', $old_from_date_timestamp);

$old_to_date = $row['ToDate'];
$old_to_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_to_date);
$new_to_date = date('d/m/Y', $old_to_date_timestamp);

echo "<p align='center'>THIS IS TO CERTIFY THAT <u>".$row['Name']."</u> IS RECEIVING   MEDICAL</p>";
echo "<p align='center'>TREATMENT AND FOR THE PERIOD <u>".$new_from_date."</u> TO <u>".$new_to_date."</u> INCLUSIVE</p>"; 
echo "<p align='center'>HE WILL BE UNFIT TO CONTINUE HIS USUAL OCCUPATION</p>"; 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM tblmc WHERE Id='$id'
```

You need to pass the id **$_POST['txtNo']** inside **makemc.php** to the **McReport.php** (I used **$id**).

EDIT::

**makemc.php**

```
if(session_id() == '') {     
    session_start();    
}     
$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['txtNo'];
```

**McReport.php**

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblmc WHERE Id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: so at makemc.php must put $id = $_POST['txtNo']; ??

Comment: yes, but you need to pass this $id to the McReport.php.
The simplest way could be the SESSION.
Make sure you've initialized it in the **makemc.php** with
`if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}`

Assign the $_SESSION['id']
`$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['txtNo']`

And in the **McReport.php** use this query
`$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblmc WHERE Id='$id'") or die(mysql_error()); `

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$row` before defining it / retrieveing data from the database:

```
...

include("database.php"); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblmc") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

$row = mysql_fetch_array($data); // get the first row from the database

$old_from_date = $row['FromDate'];
...
```

This only valid if and if you actually get 1 (one) row. The query seems to retrieve the entire table, so you either restrict by a `WHERE` clause or put that into a loop:

```
...

include("database.php"); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblmc") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

$row = false;
do {

   $row = mysql_fetch_array($data); // get the first row from the database

   $old_from_date = $row['FromDate'];
   ... // your code here

} while ( $row !== false );
```